# Prove that $M = \mathbb Z^+$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> Let $M$ be a nonempty subset of $\mathbb Z^+$ such that for every element $x$ in $M,$ the numbers $4x$ and $\lfloor \sqrt x \rfloor$ also belong to $M.$ Prove that $M = \mathbb Z^+$.

Suppose $a \in M$. Then so are $4ak$ and $\lfloor \sqrt{4ak} \rfloor$ for every positive integer multiple of $k$. Also we could take a multiple of $4$, then do the square root and floor it etc. in many different combinations. How do we prove that $M$ is all of $\mathbb{Z}^+$?

Comment: It could be useful to see that $\lfloor \sqrt{4ak} \rfloor= \lfloor 2\sqrt{ak} \rfloor$.

Comment: How did you deduce $4ak \in M$?

Answer (score 2):

Starting at any $m \in M$ and repeatedly applying $f(x)=[\sqrt{x}]$ (I use $[u]$ for floor of $u$) one eventually gets $1 \in M,$ then repeatedly multiplying by $4$ we have $4^k \in M,$ then applying $f$ to these we have $2^k \in M$ for all $k,$ i.e. $M$ contains the powers of $2.$
In what follows we use "integer intervals" like $[r,s)$ to mean the intersection of the corresponding intervals of reals with the integers. In particular for any $x,$ $[x,x+1)$ just means the singleton $\{x\},$ and for example $[1,5)$ consists of $\{1,2,3,4\}.$

We will be interested in the inverse image under $f$ of one of these integer intervals $[a,b),$ and claim that inverse image is $[a^2,b^2).$ This is easy to check. In turn, the inverse image of *that* inverse image of $[a,b)$ will be $[a^4,b^4).$ The idea of the rest of the proof that one can get a number $m$ is to show that a high enough inverse image of the interval $[m,m+1)$ will contain at least one power of $2,$ and since we know these are in $M,$ we can get to $m$ from some high enough power of $2$ on applying $f$ enough times.

So for fixed $m$ and  $k \ge 1$ let $I_k$ be the interval
$$I_k=[m^{2^k},\ (m+1)^{2^k}).$$
Any integer in $I_k$ will, after $k$ applications of $f,$ give $m.$ So we just need to show that for large enough $k$ there is a power of $2$ in $I_k.$ To avoid the problem at the right endpoint that we don't want the only such power of 2 to be that endpoint, we proceed to arrange that in fact there be at least *two* powers of $2$ in $I_k.$

We use the notation $\rm{lg}\  x$ for the log base $2,$ and note that $2^r \in I_k$ is equivalent to $r$ lying somewhere in the interval

$$J_k=[2^k \rm{lg} (m),\  2^k \rm{lg} (m+1)).$$

So if we take $k$ large enough that $J_k$ has length greater than $2,$ then there will be two values of $r$ in interval $J_k,$ and so there will be two different values of $k$ such that $2^k$ lies in interval $I_k$ as desired. Now the length of interval $J_k$ is $2^k\ \rm{lg}\frac{m+1}{m},$ so we can easily make $J_k$ have length greater than $2.$

*Added later:* As @user84413 points out in a comment, we only need the length of $J_k$ to be at least 1. It is a half-open interval of reals, and any such interval of length 1 or more will have an integer in it, which can be the $r$ from which $2^r$ lies in $I_k.$ This cuts down the size if computing an example.

Comment: (+1) nice solution, explained well.  (This is a minor point, but would it suffice to make the length of $J_k$ greater than 1, since then there would be an $r$ with $2^k lg(m)<r<2^k lg(m+1)$?)

Comment: @user84413 I thought maybe length greater than one would suffice, but was worried about the power of 2 being only at the right endpoint, so thought why not make the length greater than two, and then the lower power of 2 would definitely not be at the right endpoint. You may be right however. (Since I was just going for an existence proof it doesn't matter to use a larger $k$ than needed.)

Comment: You're right that there is no harm in specifying that the length is larger than 2. Anyway, it's a nice answer to a fun problem!

Comment: @user84413 I've mulled it over and now think it's clear we only need length at least $1$ for $J_k.$ [added that to answer, citing your comment]

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact that $\lfloor \sqrt{x} \rfloor \in M$ for every $x \in M$ to show that $1 \in M$, hence $M$ contains every multiple of $4$. To finish, use the fact that there is always a multiple of $4$ between any two consecutive squares.

Comment: Ah, clever. +1.

Comment: is it immediate that you get the multiples of $4$?, the obvious thing is that you get the powers of $4$.

Comment: How does this prove for example we get $2,3$ between $1$ and $4$?

Comment: @Puzzled417 if you have 9 and 4 then you also have their square roots, I am not sure how he argues we have the multiples of 4 though

Comment: @clark Yeah, my mistake. I didn't think it through carefully enough.

Comment: This is far from an answer, as we can see from the comments. It takes some doing even to arrive at $3,$ and $7$ takes even more steps.